# Equivalent of @JsonIgnoreProperties for XML in java serialization?

Tags: java, json, xml, serialization

I am able to ignore specific property/specific attribute in the property using @JsonIgnoreProperties.

What is the equivalent of @JsonIgnoreProperties for XML in java serialization ?

Comment: Do you mean JAXB?

Comment: If you are using fasterxml's `XmlMapper()` then `@JsonIgnoreProperties` will work for xml as well.